# OOP PHP output data from class function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function within a class that queries the MySQL database for data, which will grab about 10 rows from the database.

Example code:

```
<?php

 class details {

 public function detailsRetrieve() { 
    try {

        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $1 = $row['row1'];
        $2 = $row['row2'];
        $3 = $row['row3'];
        $4 = $row['row4'];

        }

    $con = null;   

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

    }
 }   
     }
     ?>
```

Now that works fine and gets the data from the database.
I have included the class in a seperate page like so:

```
    <?php
    include("class/details.php"); 
    $class = new details();
    $class->detailsRetrieve();
    ?>
```

How can I actually output the variable (1,2,3,4) on this new page?

I know that if I echo each of those variables inside of the function they will automaticly show on the new page just by using the above code, but I can I output each one seperately where I need on the page?

Comment: You need to `return` something from that method. PDOs `->fetchAll` would make more sense for multiple result rows.

Comment: A variable name beginning with a numeric is invalid, so your code should generate an error.... create an array of your result rows, and return that array from the class method

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `detailsRetrieve()` return the values. Then you can access them in your page.

```
public function detailsRetrieve() { 
    try {

        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        $results = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $results() = $row;
        }

    $con = null;   

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

    }
 }   

 $details = $class->detailsRetrieve();

 foreach ($details as $row) 
 {
     echo 'row 1: ' . $row['row1'] . '<br>';
     echo 'row 2: ' . $row['row2'] . '<br>';
     echo 'row 3: ' . $row['row3'] . '<br>';
     echo 'row 4: ' . $row['row4'] . '<br>';
  }
```

Comment: but you're violating `single responsibility principle`

Answer (score 0):

Class

```
class details {

    public function detailsRetrieve() { 
        try {

            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
            $result = $con->query($sql);

            while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY)) {
                $ret[] = array('1' => $row['row1'],
                '2' => $row['row2'],
                '3' => $row['row3'],
                '4' => $row['row4']);
            }

        $con = null;   

        if (!empty($ret)) return $ret;
        return array();

        }catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage();

        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Second file:

```
<?php

$det = new details();
$arr = $det->detailsRetrive();

print("<pre>");
print_r($arr);
print("</pre>");

?>
```